# MUI AppBar does not use transition when opening or closing when using Styled in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I've created a component that wraps the MUI AppBar, imports my state store (from Zustand), creates a styled component and then renders the result. Everything works fine apart from the transition effects between the open and closed state.

I've tried passing the props down instead of pulling the data in from the store, useMemo in case the component was being re-rendered unnecessarily and setting a local state object using useState and useEffect.

I don't often write React so if anybody can point me to something I'm doing that's obviously wrong I'd really appreciate it. The AppBar code is as follows:

```
"use client";
import {type Theme, styled, type CSSObject} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {Drawer as MuiDrawer} from '@/lib/mui';
import useLayoutStore from "~/stores/app-store";
import React, {type ComponentPropsWithRef} from "react";

type ExtendedProps = ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof MuiDrawer>;

const AppDrawer : React.FC<ExtendedProps> = ({children, ...props}) => {
    const state = useLayoutStore();

    const openedMixin = (theme:Theme) : CSSObject => ({
        width: state.drawerWidth,
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        })
    });

    const closedMixin = (theme:Theme) : CSSObject => ({
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
        },
    });

    const StyledAppDrawer = styled(MuiDrawer)(({theme}) => ({
            flexShrink: 0,
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            ...(state.open && {
                ...openedMixin(theme),
                '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
            }),
            ...(!state.open && {
                ...closedMixin(theme),
                '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
            }),
        }
    )) as typeof MuiDrawer;
    return (<StyledAppDrawer open={state.open} {...props}>{children}</StyledAppDrawer>);
};

export default AppDrawer;
```